# Не могу понять, что не так. Задача на функцию

Tags: python

Напиши функцию filt_by_creation_data(), которая наполняет таблицу всеми картинами, созданными с 1800 по 1900 годы. Написать их сумму (0 по индексу в каждом вложенном списке), название картины (1 по индексу в каждом вложенном списке), год создания (2 по индексу в каждом вложенном списку).

```
art_market_dataset = [
    [112.7, 'Стога сена', 1890 , 2019, 'Клод Моне ', 'Пейзаж', 5],
    [90.4, 'Буффало 2', 1964, 2019, 'Роберт Раушенберг ', 'Фигуративная Живопись', 10],
    [60.4, 'Кувшин и фрукты', 1890, 2019, 'Поль Сезанн ', 'Натюрморт', 6],
    [163.0, 'Лежащая обнажённая', 1917, 2018, 'Амедео Модильяни ', 'Ню', 7],
    [119.2, 'Молодая девушка с цветочной корзиной', 1905, 2018, 'Пабло Пикассо ', 'Ню', 7],
    [95.2, 'Чоп суэй', 1929, 2018, 'Эдвард Хоппер ', 'Жанровая живопись', 7],
    [478.1, 'Спаситель мира', 1500, 2017, 'Леонардо да Винчи ', 'Портрет', 10],
    [149.6, 'Двенадцать ландшафтных сцен', 1925, 2017, 'Ци Байши ', 'Пейзаж', 4],
    [117.3, 'Без названия (1982)', 1982, 2017, 'Жан-Мишель Баския ', 'Фигуративная Живопись', 3],
    [88.3, 'Стог сена', 1891, 2016, 'Клод Моне ', 'Пейзаж', 5],
    [71.9, 'Без названия XXV', 1977, 2016, 'Виллем де Кунинг ', 'Композиция', 1],
    [68.5, 'Сидящая женщина', 1909, 2016, 'Пабло Пикассо ', 'Портрет', 3],
    [194.5, 'Алжирские женщины («Версия O»)', 1955, 2015, 'Пабло Пикассо ', 'Жанровая живопись', 3],
    [184.8, "Обнаженная, лежащая на левом боку", 1918, 2015, 'Амедео Модильяни ', 'Ню', 7],
    [103.4, 'Медсестра', 1964, 2015, 'Рой Лихтенштейн ', 'Портрет', 7],
    [81.3, 'Черный огонь I', 1961, 2014, 'Барнетт Ньюмен ', 'Композиция', 1],
    [79.2, 'Тройной Элвис', 1963, 2014, 'Энди Уорхол ', 'Портрет', 10],
    [78.1, 'Три наброска к портрету Джона Эдвардса', 1984, 2014, 'Фрэнсис Бэкон ', 'Портрет', 6],
    [141.9, 'Три наброска к портрету Люсьена Фрейда', 1969, 2013, 'Фрэнсис Бэкон ', 'Портрет', 6],
    [105.0, 'Авария серебряной машины (Двойная катастрофа)', 1963, 2013, 'Энди Уорхол ', 'Жанровая живопись', 10],
    [58.1, "Номер 19, 1948", 1948, 2013, 'Джексон Поллок ', 'Композиция', 1],
    [121.3, "Крик, 1895", 1895, 2012, 'Эдвард Мунк ', 'Жанровая живопись', 4],
    [87.8, "Оранжевый, красный, жёлтый", 1961, 2012, 'Марк Ротко ', 'Композиция', 1],
    [75.9, '№ 1 (Королевский красный и голубой)', 1954, 2012, 'Марк Ротко ', 'Композиция', 1],
    [64.8, 'Орел на сосне', 1946, 2011, 'Ци Байши ', 'Пейзаж', 4],
    [62.3, '1949-A-No.1', 1949, 2011, 'Клиффорд Стилл ', 'Композиция', 1],
    [61.3, 'Чжи Чуань поднимается в гору', 1370, 2011, 'Ван Мэн ', 'Жанровая живопись', 4],
    [107.7, "Обнажённая, зелёные листья и бюст", 1932, 2010, 'Пабло Пикассо ', 'Портрет', 2],
    [69.7, "Обнажённая, сидящая на диване", 1917, 2010, 'Амедео Модильяни ', 'Ню', 7],
    [64.0, 'Мужчины в ее жизни', 1962, 2010, 'Энди Уорхол ', 'Портрет', 10],
    [44.2, 'Голова музы', 1511, 2009, 'Рафаэль ', 'Портрет', 10],
    [45.2, 'Часы с кукушкой и ковер в синих и красных тонах', 1911, 2009, 'Анри Матисс ', 'Натюрморт', 5],
    [47.3, '200 однодолларовых купюр', 1962, 2009, 'Энди Уорхол ', 'Композиция', 10],
    [93.1, "Триптих, 1976", 1976, 2008, 'Фрэнсис Бэкон ', 'Портрет', 6],
    [61.8, 'Пруд с водяными лилиями', 1919, 2008, 'Клод Моне ', 'Пейзаж', 5],
    [64.7, 'Супрематическая композиция', 1919, 2008, 'Казимир Малевич ', 'Композиция', 1],
    [81.6, "Белый центр (жёлтое, розовое и лиловое на розовом)", 1950, 2007, 'Марк Ротко ', 'Композиция', 1],
    [52.7, 'Набросок к портрету папы Иннокентия X', 1962, 2007, 'Фрэнсис Бэкон ', 'Портрет', 6],
    [89.9, 'Авария зелёной машины', 1963, 2007, 'Энди Уорхол ', 'Жанровая живопись', 10],
    [109.7, 'Дора Маар с кошкой', 1941, 2006, 'Пабло Пикассо ', 'Портрет', 3],
    [101.3, 'Портрет Адели Блох-Бауэр II', 1912, 2006, 'Густав Климт ', 'Портрет', 8],
    [46.5, 'Мужчина с топором', 1891, 2006, 'Поль Гоген ', 'Жанровая живопись', 5],
    [34.3, "Венеция: Гранд канал, вид с северо-востока от Палаццо Балби на мост Риальто", 1724, 2005, 'Каналетто ', 'Пейзаж', 10],
    [25.8, 'Прачка', 1886, 2005, 'Анри де Тулуз-Лотрек ', 'Портрет', 10],
    [25.8, 'Дань уважения Матиссу', 1954, 2005, 'Марк Ротко ', 'Композиция', 1]
]
```

Но при таком коде

```
def filt_by_creation_data(data):
  x = []
  for picters in range(len(data)):
    if data[picters][2] >= 1800 and data[picters][2] < 1900:
      x.append(picters)
 for i in x:
   print(f'{x[i][0]: <16.1f} | {x[i][1]: <20} | {x[i][2]: <0}')
filt_by_creation_data(art_market_dataset)
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: В `x` у вас числа. `x[i]` где `i=0` - первое число списка `x`. А что вы хотите видеть когда берёте `x[i][0]`?

Comment: Я только учу python. Просто эту тему выучил недавно и тренируюсь... Просто думал, что если мы в список x добавляем списки, то это уже списки списков. Поэтому брал два индекса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def filt_by_creation_data(data):
    x = []
    for picters in data:
        if picters[2] >= 1800 and picters[2] < 1900:
            x.append(picters)
    for i in x:
        print(f'{i[0]: <16.1f} | {i[1]: <20} | {i[2]: <0}')
```

1. В первом цикле вы записываете в список индексы найденных элементов, а не сами элементы.
2. Во втором цикле вы обращаетесь сразу к элементу, 1 индекс не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Не мог разобраться и тут сразу. Ваш ответ меня более зацепил, потому что Вы использовали функции, которые мне знакомы.

Answer (score 2):

можно воспользоваться функцией [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

да и обойтись одним циклом

```
def filt_by_creation_data(data):
    for x in filter(lambda x: 1800 <= x[2] < 1900, data):
        print(f'{x[0]: <16.1f} | {x[1]: <20} | {x[2]: <0}')
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Не мог разобраться и тут сразу.